# How to write this Subquery Select AVG with Limit in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, subquery

```
SELECT AVG(harian) a from (select harian from sla limit 2) b
```

Above is working executed in Heidisql,

And just tried below:

```
$rata2 = $this->db->query('SELECT AVG(harian) a from (select harian from sla limit 2) b');
```

But, it seems no output made, please help, thanks

Comment: Side note: SQL is a **unsorted** dataset.. Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` has no valid meaning in MySQL (or anny other DMBS which support `LIMIT` clause).. Because the SQL server is now free to return the limited records.. Which means the SQL server can pick any record from the table and return that as limited set which can be record 1 and record 2 or record 3 and record 4.. Meaning the `AVG` can change your every time you are running the query even with the same data.. So keep in mind when using `limit` use `order by` like so `select harian from sla order by <column> limit 2`

Comment: beside the fact what raymond said - i don't see any difference between your native query and the one which is wrapped in your `query` function. i can tell you how to use the QueryBuilder here - but i think it won't make any difference

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the replay and the rule, I am new in code,

So, I just added the order by and what about the syntax, I need an average value from $rata2.. Please help..

Comment: Debug with `$this->db->error();`

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland and sintakonte for the replay, as I am newbie in Javascript also, so that it is hard for me to debug this mysql query within. But the problem actually solved with my current standard sql (not using active record). I just need to return the data. I might have to ask a question about how to debug error within javascript (It worked without a javascript for me). Thanks and sorry dor my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Sub Query
$this->db->select('harian')->from('sla')->limit(2);
$subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();

// Main Query
$rata2 = $this->db->select('AVG(harian)')
     ->from($subQuery)
     ->get();

return $rata2;
```

Or if you want to return the data in array

```
// Sub Query
$this->db->select('harian')->from('sla')->limit(2);
$subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();

// Main Query
$rata2 = $this->db->select('AVG(harian)')
     ->from($subQuery)
     ->get()
     ->toArray();

return $rata2;
```

Comment: Hello @Leena,
Thank you for the answer, I have solved this by returning the query $rata2, because I use the $rata as a value for the next query in one function. Btw, can you show me how to return the data with your version (active record) please..

Comment: Thank you @Leena. I am learning php codeigniter, and going with a little project.
Can you please check this link as my related next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52272826/multiple-mysql-queries-in-1-function-in-model